# See SQL Server Reporting Services Reports without logging in?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have installed SQL Server 2015 with SSRS and I have some reports I need to run, but in order to access http://reportsserver/Reports I need to start Internet Explorer in administrator mode.

This is clearly suboptimal: any user would need to know the Administrator password.

How do I set up SSRS to not require auth to see reports, or how can I make users not need to run IE in Administrator mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to run in Administrator mode because you haven't added any users to SSRS. You need to grant permissions. For example on the root folder in SSRS add a windows user/group to the Browser role.

For more details see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156014%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Oh, I missed that it was a per-folder configuration. I was adding users with the "Site Configuration" tab, and it wasn't doing anything. Thank you! I'll mark as accepted soon.